# How to include class definition through "this" keyword in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm creating a class that extend `HttpClient` then extending `this` keyword through `includeEventsIn` function, `includeEventsIn` will extend BaseService with EventAggregator type, see code [here](https://github.com/aurelia/event-aggregator/blob/master/src/index.js#L141).

**Question**

- How can I include `EventAggregator` methods and props in `BaseService` class along with HttpClient?
- What would be another approach to extend class(BaseService) with two class?

Here's the code.

```
@transient()
export class BaseService extends HttpClient {
    constructor() {
        super();
        includeEventsIn(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to inject `EventAggreator` in the `BaseClass`. However, I think it would make more sense if you inject both `HttpClient` and `EventAggregator` in the `BaseClass`, without using inheritance...

Comment: The methods and property of EventAggregator and HttpClient would not be available for baseclass. I don't want to inject it as it will need to implement manually all its properties and methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use inheritance when building Aurelia apps unless absolutely necessary (and I would argue it's never necessary). Favor composition over inheritance.

For example, in your case, I would have `Service` (not `BaseService`, because you would no longer be using inheritance) take a dependency on `HttpClient` and `EventAggregator`. I doubt you truly need all of the functionality that gets added by the call to `includeEventsIn`. That being said, if you do need it, then you can simply add the three functions to `Service`.

```
import {inject, EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@inject(HttpClient, EventAggregator)
export class Service {
  constructor( http, ea ) {
    this.http = http;
    this.ea = ea;
  }
}
```

You can then inject this class in to another class as needed, after implementing whatever functionality it needs.

Comment: It makes sense. But for the sake of the question, is it possible in typescript to extend class definition(props and method) through this keyword  when using includeEventsIn?

Comment: I would look at creating a decorator to do that. `includeEventsIn` is kind of a mix-in type thing.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking after searching, but no idea how to implement. You can update your answer if you have one, thanks​

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to put the decorator in this answer as it would just muddy things up. But you can check out the docs for decorators here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: For this problem, exposing only what the Baseclass needs seems the only best way instead of exposing public members of EventAggregator and HttpClient in BaseClass.